# IPTables Port Redirection Should Have Broken Apache But Didn't

Tags: linux, iptables, tomcat, apache-httpd

I have a Load Balance set up in Apache `httpd`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.com
        ProxyRequests           Off
        ProxyPreserveHost       On
        ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

`:8080` is an Apache `tomcat` application server running on the same host. We have log retention requirements where I work, so I figured making everything apache `httpd` would make things ideal for analytics.

I was attempting to get all public requests to go through port 80 without breaking any links or bookmarks end users might have. I was going to do that by doing some port translation so that everything looked like it was coming in via port 80 to applications. Without thinking about my load balance above I added the following rules to the `nat` table:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
```

Problem is, that I can get to the application either through `httpd` or directly by going to `:8080`. The packet count is also going up on each rule so apparently they're being matched against.

My question is this: **Why didn't this just create an infinite loop?**

It would seem the `:8080` requests would get forwarded to `httpd` which would itself attempt to retrieve them by going over `:8080` and thus the circle would continue onwards until I was reformatting my new resume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in `-i eth0`.

Even though you have httpd set to connect to `17.98.65.28`, which I assume is an IP on `eth0`, the traffic won't actually flow over `eth0`, it'll use `lo` instead.

The reason for this is that when routing to any IP the box has on itself, that traffic flows over `lo`. You can verify this with the following:

```
ip route get 17.98.65.28
```

You will get a line back that contains `dev lo`, this tells you which interface will be used to send traffic to that address.

For example, on my laptop, I have `wlan0` with `10.252.28.62`:

```
$ ip route get 10.252.28.62
local 10.252.28.62 dev lo  src 10.252.28.62 
    cache <local>
```